# Can no longer connect to server (an error occurred during the pre-login handshake)

Tags: windows, sql-server, tcp, rdp, connection

Apologies if this isn't the place to ask this, or if it isn't enough information to go off of. I'm pretty new at this and don't know what or where else to ask.

Since two nights ago, nobody can connect to our server. Before this I could connect to the SQL Server and through Remote Desktop Connection. Then suddenly overnight, neither work.

SSMS gives the following error message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

RDP gets caught up on the "Securing remote connection..." step.

The server is on and connected to the internet just fine.
No firewall settings have changed, unless there is some automatic thing in Windows that I don't know about.
The IP address of neither the server nor the network it's on has changed, and neither has the network's port forwarding settings.
Using a TCP port scan, it reveals that the relevant ports are still open. Same IP, same ports. And I was able to connect successfully these ways many times.

Does anyone know where I can start looking to fix this? Any idea what could have caused this problem so I can start looking for solutions and prevent this from happening again? What automatic process could cause an overnight change like this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are trying to connect with an encrypted connection and the servers certificate is not trusted anymore (or just expired).

Try first to connect with the option "trust server certificate" for example in SSMS with klick on `Options >>` in the `Connection Properties` tab.

For investigating this issue you could also try to connect via mmc and
Event Viewer or other consoles to this host.